# How to hide unity multiplayer connection info.?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I am trying to develop a unity multiplayer game. I want to hide information of port like other games.I post image You can chack it. I want to change stop button to quit but not How.?

[image]

Any one can help me, tell me How to do this like other games, What shoudl I do.
Should I need to change scene after connection success(all player connected).?

Comment: I don't clearly understand your question. Do you want to hide the information displayed on the screen? If so, you have a script implementing `OnGUI` function. Check it and remove what you don't want to see on the screen.

Comment: This information comes from "Network Manager HUD" so, How can I hide this. Where is OnGUI function available.?

Comment: Open the script `Network Manager HUD` and find the `OnGUI` function inside it.

Comment: Can't open it, it say file not found error. also should I change this system file.?

Comment: According to the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-NetworkManagerHUD.html), you can uncheck the `showGUI` checkbox to hide these information.

Comment: I see that before posting here, but I can't able to implement it in own script. because I can access only network manager not network managerHUD.

Comment: Uncheck it using the inspector. In the `Hierarchy` tab of Unity, click on the search bar and type "t:NetworkManagerHUD". You should see the object holding the `NetworkManagerHUD` component. Simply uncheck the `ShowRuntimeGUI`

Comment: If I uncheck it from inspector then How can I able to select/ click Host/client.? Do you understand me.? that's why I need to access this with script. I want to hide above image info. after join the game.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159035/discussion-between-moje-mast-ram-and-hellium).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The information displayed on your screen come from the [`NetworkManagerHUD`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManagerHUD.html).

In order to hide these information, you have to set [`showGUI`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.NetworkManagerHUD-showGUI.html) boolean to false.

In order to do so, either uncheck it from the inspector or use the following line of code once your players are connected :

```
NetworkManagerHUD hud = FindObjectOfType<NetworkManagerHUD>();
if( hud != null )
    hud.showGUI = false;
```